# How to use Rails named route helpers with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

given this route

```
match 'posts/hello/:name/:title' => 'post#show', :as => :hello
```

- what are the ways that I can call `hello_path` ?
- if i call `hello_path(@post)`, what does it try to do?

I was hoping that the `:name` and `:title` files will bind to the path automatically but it seems that rails only know how to get the :id out of the model object.

instead, it only works if I call it like

```
<%= link_to "link2", hello_url(:name=> @post.name, :title=>@post.title) %>
```

(lack of proper documentation is really killing me)

Answer (score 25):

To answer your two questions:

- At the command line, run`rake routes` to see what routes there are in
  your app. It will show you all the ways you can use the named routes,
  just add "_path" or "_url" to the name of the route which is shown on
  the left.
- Calling `hello_path(@post)` will generate a URL to the
  **show** page for that `hello` instance.

The way you are calling it is the norm:

```
<%= link_to "link2", hello_url(:name=> @post.name, :title=>@post.title) %>
```

However, this may work too:

```
<%= link_to "link2", hello_url(@post.name, @post.title) %>
```

Here is some documentation (other than the Rails API) which should help.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GregT, but I think the question 'if i call `hello_path(@post)`, what does it try to do?' is actually asking "shouldn't the path helper try to call name and title on the post, and populate the path correctly? (e.g. if post.name is 'bam' and post.title is 'kapow', shouldn't `hello_path(@post)` return 'posts/hello/bam/kapow'? And if not, what is it actually trying to do?)" I am currently looking for the answer to this as well. If you have any insight, that would be fantastic.

Comment: I did answer the question but I'll be more explicit: you are probably calling a different route than you think you are. This is because routes can conflict with each other, and the first one wins (top to bottom in `routes.rb`). You probably have `resource :posts` above `match 'posts/hello/:name/:title' => 'post#show', :as => :hello`, so what is happening is that **it is generating the route for SHOW a post `/posts/123`**. You can fix this by moving your custom route ABOVE the call to `resource :posts` and restart your server.

Answer (score 17):

### To answer your question of "what does `hello_path` try to do?"

`hello_path` knows how many parameters it's supposed to get. This is from counting the named parameters in `config/routes`. It will accept either a hash or a list of arguments. If you give it a hash, the keys must match the names of the URL parameters. If you give it a list of arguments, it'll just match them up by position - the first argument with the first named parameter.

Then, it will call `to_param` on **each** parameter individually before joining them all together ([see code here, 4.0 branch](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L494)).

If you pass in an object when it's expecting 2 or more params, it won't even get around to calling to_param on the object. That's when you get errors with no stack trace that say something like
`No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show", :id=>#<Post ...>}`

### Working with 1 named parameter

If you've only got one named parameter, things are pretty straightforward.  If you need to look up your posts by name instead of id, you can just redefine `to_param`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

### Working with multiple named parameters

But if the URL has more than one named parameter in it, then redefining `to_param` isn't enough. Let's say you tried this:

```
# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_param
    {name: name, title: title}
  end
end

# app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<%= post_path(post) %>
```

In this case, you'll get a routing error because you're not passing in enough arguments to post_path (see above). **To get around this, I just call `to_param` explicitly:**

```
 # app/views/posts/index.html.erb
 <%= post_path(post.to_param) %>
```

This is a little less slick than most Rails routing magic, but works perfectly well. If you later change the way you're looking up Posts, all you have to do is redefine to_param. No need to worry about all the places you've called `post_path`

### Under the hood

The relevant code to look at is [actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing)

Answer (score 6):

You can also call it like this

```
hello_path(@post.name, @post.title)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers (at the time of this writing) are fine, but your reply to GregT's answer shows a lack of understand about Rails, which is fine -- we've all been there.

Specifically, three of the key principles behind Rails: **convention over configuration**, the **model-view-controller architecture** (MVC), and **REST**. It's stuff at the beginning of every beginning Rails book. Beginners often think they can just jump to the first chapter with code, but Rails differs from many other topics in that the first chapters explain important concepts and aren't just intro chapter filler. Because Rails isn't "code", it's a "framework of code".

"Convention over configuration" means if you follow certain conventions then you benefit from behaviors baked into Rails. Routing is one of those areas, if not the biggest, where convention benefits the developer although it is entirely configurable.

Paths following a specific routing format, are parsed into the controller, action and possibly an id, format, and additional parameters. By default and at minimum, a Rails (and also a Sinatra) path takes the following format and order:

```
/controller_name/action_name
```

It's a little more complicated than that, with more options, and it looks more like this in actuality:

```
/controller_name/action_name/(id)(.format)(?param=value)(&...)
```

...but it's more detail than is necessary for this answer.

The *controller* is the C in MVC, or the class that handles the request. The *action* is one of the seven RESTful actions (`index`, `show`, `new`, `create`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy`) within that controller. Not all actions require an id (`index`, `new` and `create`) and not all of them are `get` requests (requests that generate a view, for instance `destroy`, `create` and `update` don't have views).

Putting it all together we see this example:

```
/articles/edit/1
```

...will route the request to the 'edit' action in the ArticlesController controller passing along id 1. It's expected that the controller will do some housekeeping, like authentication and authorization, then retrieve Article model (**M**CV) with ID 1 and pass it along to the "edit" view (MC**V**).

It's best, especially for new Rails developers, to stick to these conventions and perhaps add a few additional actions beyond those provided by REST.

You can step outside this convention by configuring in your routes.rb file an alternative routing scheme, not following REST, etc., but you'll be like a salmon swimming upstream -- it's a lot harder than going with the flow. If you go down that path (pun) you'll make a lot of additional work for yourself, probably reinvent the wheel somewhat, and lose advantages provided by the Rails framework. If you find yourself in that situation for whatever reason, perhaps Rails isn't the right tool for your job.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this as it is well-articulated but: it does nothing to answer the posters question, and B, Any enterprise architecture running rails will quickly run into a feature which needs more than just the convention that the framework provides. Rails does offer loopholes to break REST. It can be abused, and you are correct with the salmon analogy. I just think your response is too idealized for common industry usage.

Comment: Thanks for not downvoting and your compliment. You are right and I should have supplied more named route equivalents for illustration and mentioned the `rake routes` command. Your "conformant" criticism is appreciated, and I agree. I meant to say that REST should be the starting place from which to break out from where necessary, rather than creating your own routing scheme from scratch as your starting place. I'm not advocating a pure RESTful design unless it makes sense in the real world, and we all know that's rarely the case. If you don't need REST at all maybe sinatra is for you.