# Couldn't find Object with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

stumped here, probably due to my rails noobness.

I am building a 2 sided market place with bids. using devise for 2 user types relevant here, clients and guides. clients build a trip, guides can view trips and then bid on the trip. i've created a custom landing page for the guides (home) once they sign in which lists client trips, i use a custom view and method in my guides controller to do this, no problem.

however, when from that page i try to go to the next custom page for the guide to view the details of the trip (and then submit a bid), suddenly i get a "Couldn't find Trip with 'id'=" error related to the Trip.find(params[:id]) (if i hardcode Trip.find(1) it works).

guides controller

```
class GuidesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @trips = Trip.all
    @guide = current_guide
  end

  def view_trip
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
    @guide = current_guide
  end
end
```

guide's home page (which is where the guide clicks to view the trip)

```
<p>Guides's Email: <%= @guide.email %></p>
<% @trips.each do |trip| %>
  <li>Location: <%= trip.location.description %></li>
  <li>Details <%= trip.details %></li> 
  <p><%= link_to "View Details and Bid", guides_view_trip_path(trip) %></p>
<% end %>
```

and then the error output at the page when i try to visit it/click on the link: amazonaws.com/guides/view_trip.1

```
Couldn't find Trip with 'id'=
Extracted source (around line #21):

19  def view_trip
20
21      @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
22      #@trip = Trip.find(1)
23      @guide = current_guide
24  end

Request
Parameters:
{"format"=>"1"}
```

Comment: That `.1` in your url `amazonaws.com/guides/view_trip.1` suggests you are using the wrong path. It might help if you show your routes configuration.

Comment: `Trip.find(params[:id])` should be `Trip.find(params[:format])`.

Comment: show your file routes.rb.

Comment: @MikeN. Let's try the below answer and see what happening

Comment: Hi, I believe you're new to SO. If my answer (or any other) solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark, so that the question is not pending anymore. Many users (including myself :) are looking for pending questions to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
<p><%= link_to "View Details and Bid", guides_view_trip_path(trip) %></p>
```

By

```
<p><%= link_to "View Details and Bid", guides_view_trip_path(id: trip.id) %></p>
```

Comment: thanks! that did it, i'm curious as to why passing the object alone wasn't enough for the controller, but maybe because the find was looking for a param value and not the object itself?

Comment: You should show your routes. You have a nice explanation about routes in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26415546/3372172 and in official documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your `routes.rb` design, if you need to take this URL with rails default `RESTful` URL then your `routes.rb` looks like this

```
get 'guides/view_trip/:id(.:format)', to: "guides#view_trip", as: :guides_view_trip

#=>  guides_view_trip GET  /guides/view_trip/:id(.:format) guides#view_trip
```

Now you can use the view like below

```
<%= link_to "View Details and Bid", guides_view_trip_path(trip) %>
#=> /guides/view_trip/1
```

If you use `guides_view_trip_path(id: trip.id)` then URL looks like this `amazonaws.com/guides/view_trip?id=1` and if you use `RESTful` which I described then looks like this `amazonaws.com/guides/view_trip/1`

Or you can use `Trip.find(params[:id])` to `Trip.find(params[:format])`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like that

```
class GuidesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @trips = Trip.all
    @guide = current_guide
  end

  def view_trip
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:format])
    @guide = current_guide
  end
end
```